# "Not enough storage" error reading from numpy memmap

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I've managed to successfully write to a NumPy memory map with the following command:

```
recipe_map = np.memmap(memmap_file, dtype=np.dtype('a25'), mode='w+', shape=(832, 4, 1000, 2))
```

When I try to load the same memory map with the command:

```
recipe_map = np.memmap(memmap_file, dtype=np.dtype('a25'), mode='r', shape=(832, 4, 1000, 2))
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 8] Not enough storage is available to process this command
```

I'm running 64-bit Python 3.4.4. The value of 'bytes' when the mmap object is implemented is 166400000, which is well under my ceiling of 2147483647 for numpy. Why would I be able to write to this array but not read from it?

Comment: In case anyone sees this and is interested, changing the mode flag to r+ seems to work